# how to use material-ui select field with formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I'm tryin to use formik with material-ui Textfield componet with select attr, everytime i change option it gives me this Warning

> Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `null` for the select (name="subIndicatorId") component.
> Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
> The available values are `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `55`, `161`, `162`, `163`, `164`, `193`, `233`, `234`, `235`, `236`, `237`, `238`, `239`, `240`, `241`, `242`, `243`, `244`, `245`, `246`, `262`, `263`, `264`, `265`, `266`, `267`, `268`, `271`, `286`, `288`, `289`, `295`, `300`, `303`, `304`, `306`, `307`, `311`, `341`

alsol i get this Warning when the page render first time

> Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.

here is the code for this

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

import { Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";

import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";

import { axios } from "../Axios/Axios";

import icommodityGroup from "../../assets/images/png/product.png";
import wheatBag from "../../assets/images/png/Wheat Bag.png";
import flag from "../../assets/images/png/flag.png";
import { MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";

const RetailPrices = () => {
  const [genralIndicators, setGenralIndicators] = useState([]);
  const [governorates, setGovernorate] = useState([]);
  const [subIndicator, setSubIndicator] = useState([]);
  const [classification, setClassification] = useState();

  const getPopulate = async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get("/home/PopulateDropDowns")
      .catch((err) => console.log("Error", err)); //handle errors
    if (response && response.data) {
      console.log(response);
      setGenralIndicators(response.data.genralIndicators);
      setGovernorate(response.data.governorates);
      setClassification(response.data.classification);
    }
  };

  const getSubindicator = async (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    const response = await axios
      .get(`/home/SubIndicator/${id}`)
      .catch((err) => console.log("Error", err)); //handle errors
    if (response && response.data) {
      setSubIndicator(response.data);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPopulate();
  }, []);

  const handleGenralIndicatorsChange = (e) => {
    getSubindicator(e.target.value);
  };

  // Schema for yup
  const validationSchema = yup.object({
    commodityGroup: yup
      .string("أختر المجموعة السلعية")
      .required("أختر المجموعة السلعية "),
    // commodity: yup.string("أختر السلعة").required("أختر السلعة"),
    // city: yup.string("أختر المدينة").required("أختر المدينة"),
  });

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      ClassificationId: 1,
      GeneralIndicatorId: null,
      GovernorateId: null,
      subIndicatorId: null,
    },
    // validationSchema: validationSchema,

    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      const response = await axios
        .post("/home/PriceSearch", JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
        .catch((err) => console.log("Error", err)); //handle errors;
      if (response) {
        alert("sucess!");
        console.log(response);
      }
    },
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <Row>
          <Col className="px-0">
            <img
              className="p-1"
              src={icommodityGroup}
              alt="icon_1"
              style={{
                borderRadius: "6px",
                boxShadow: "10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.36)",
              }}
            />

            <TextField
              style={{ width: "200px" }}
              className="px-2 my-2"
              variant="outlined"
              name="GeneralIndicatorId"
              id="المجموعة السلعية"
              select
              label="المجموعة السلعية"
              value={formik.values.GeneralIndicatorId}
              onChange={(e) => {
                formik.handleChange(e);
                handleGenralIndicatorsChange(e);
              }}
              error={
                formik.touched.genralIndicators &&
                Boolean(formik.errors.genralIndicators)
              }
              helperText={
                formik.touched.genralIndicators &&
                formik.errors.genralIndicators
              }
            >
              {genralIndicators.map((option) => (
                <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
                  {option.name}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </TextField>
          </Col>
          <Col className="px-0">
            <img
              className="p-1"
              src={wheatBag}
              alt="icon_1"
              style={{
                borderRadius: "6px",
                boxShadow: "10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.36)",
              }}
            />
            <TextField
              style={{ width: "200px" }}
              className="px-2 my-2"
              variant="outlined"
              name="subIndicatorId"
              id="السلعة"
              select
              label="السلعة"
              value={formik.values.subIndicatorId}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={
                formik.touched.subIndicator &&
                Boolean(formik.errors.subIndicator)
              }
              helperText={
                formik.touched.subIndicator && formik.errors.subIndicator
              }
            >
              {subIndicator.map((option) => (
                <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
                  {option.name}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </TextField>
          </Col>
          <Col className="px-0">
            <img
              className="p-1"
              src={flag}
              alt="icon_1"
              style={{
                borderRadius: "6px",
                boxShadow: "10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.36)",
              }}
            />
            <TextField
              style={{ width: "200px" }}
              className="px-2 my-2"
              variant="outlined"
              name="GovernorateId"
              id="المحافظة"
              select
              label="المحافظة"
              value={formik.values.GovernorateId}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={
                formik.touched.governorates &&
                Boolean(formik.errors.governorates)
              }
              helperText={
                formik.touched.governorates && formik.errors.governorates
              }
            >
              {governorates.map((option) => (
                <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
                  {option.name}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </TextField>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Button
              className="p-3 my-2 "
              size="large"
              variant="contained"
              type="submit"
              style={{
                color: "#fff",
                backgroundColor: "var(--main-green)",
                width: "200px",
              }}
            >
              إرسال
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RetailPrices;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

it works fine and return response, but i want to handle these two warnings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Warning: value prop on input should not be null. Consider using an
> empty string to clear the component or undefined for uncontrolled
> components.
> Since oyu are suing controlled components, all values need to be defiend in render:

```
GeneralIndicatorId: null,
      GovernorateId: null,
      subIndicatorId: null,
```

But those are undefined/null, so setting those to `""` would fix this.

> Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value null for the
> select (name="subIndicatorId") component. Consider providing a value
> that matches one of the available options or ''.

For selects all values that are possible need to be an option, but since those are `null` and you have no null option, it throws this error. Just add a new empty option:

```
 <TextField
              style={{ width: "200px" }}
              className="px-2 my-2"
              variant="outlined"
              name="GovernorateId"
              id="المحافظة"
              select
              label="المحافظة"
              value={formik.values.GovernorateId}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={
                formik.touched.governorates &&
                Boolean(formik.errors.governorates)
              }
              helperText={
                formik.touched.governorates && formik.errors.governorates
              }
            >
               <MenuItem key={""} value={""}>
                  No Selected // Or Empty
                </MenuItem>
              {governorates.map((option) => (
                <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
                  {option.name}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </TextField>
```

Comment: it works, i added a new empty option but set its value null 
<MenuItem value={null}>No Selected</MenuItem>
just because i want to post null value to the server if the user didn't select any choice.
thank you so much